# Word wrap line option by default

Tags: customize, wrapping

Recently I discovered `emacs` as a text editor for my `latex` documents. So far, I am excited with how powerful the editor is. However, I have a problem with line wrapping.

More precisely, in the `option` menu I choose `line wrapping in this buffer --> word wrap`. After that, I choose `save options`, but when I reopen my `tex` file, line wrapping is back to the default setting.

So, my question is how can I set `word wrap` as my default wrapping option for all my documents?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you noticed, the menu entry says "Line Wrapping in *This* Buffer" so this is not something that is saved by "Save Options".

To enable `visual-line-mode` in all your latex documents, add the following in your init file (`~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`):

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'visual-line-mode)
```

This ensures the function `visual-line-mode` (aka "word wrap") is called for each buffer that is put in `LaTeX-mode` (assuming you're using AUCTeX).

More information about the hook mechanism can be found in the emacs [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html#Hooks).

Answer (score 22):

JeanPierre's answer will work fine if you want to use different word wrapping per type of document.

If you want *all* your documents word-wrapped, use the following:

```
(global-visual-line-mode t)
```

in your ~/.emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init.el file.

You can customize that value via the menus as well, by going to "Options->Customize Emacs->All Settings Matching..." and searching for "visual."

Comment: This is the right answer--the OP asked how to turn on word wrap for *all* files.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know why this isn't the default? What's the benefit of not having line-wrap? To me it's 99% just a nuisance

Comment: @mowwwalker Visual line mode seems awkward for code buffers, especially for languages where whitespace is significant.

Comment: @tikhon-jelvis That's what Hollerith format is for :)  Seriously though, I believe it's the default for historical reasons.  Visual line mode came about in Emacs 23 I believe.  Before that you had wrapping using continuation lines (the default) or by truncating the line (visually) at the right edge of the window.

Answer (score 0):

This only worked for me in my `.emacs` if the mode was not capitalized and the `#` was omitted, like this:

```
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook 'visual-line-mode)
```